# Smith normal form when vector has an entry with zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Based on the tags, I'm assuming that the $x_i$ and $a_i$ are supposed
>   to be integers. The procedure below generalizes to the case where you
>   want simultaneous solutions to multiple equations. (It also works the
>   same way if we use any principal ideal domain in place of integers.)
>
> Write the inputs as a $1 \times n$ matrix $X = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 & \dotsb & x_n\end{pmatrix}$; assume $X \ne 0$ or else the problem is
>   trivial. The problem is to find the vectors $A = \begin{pmatrix}a_1 & \dotsb & a_n\end{pmatrix}^T$ such that $XA = 0$. Smith normal form says that we can find an invertible $n \times n$ matrix $T$ such that $XT = \begin{pmatrix}d & 0 & \dotsb & 0\end{pmatrix}$, where $d = \gcd(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$. (There would also be a $1 \times 1$ matrix $S$ that goes on the left, but we can just take it to be $1$.) (from [Procedures to find solution to $a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255457/procedures-to-find-solution-to-a-1x-1-cdotsa-nx-n-0))

So, what happens if $X$ contains zero entry - but is not zero vector?